# jointjs incompatible with jquery layout plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jointjs, jquery-layout

I have a problem using jointjs and jquery-layout.
I can only use one of those, If I use both, the panel resizing doesn't work.
There is someone that have the same/similar problem? and know how to solve it?

this doesn't work at all

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<script src="joint.js"></script>
```

If I invert jquery-layout with jointjs it works, but without resizing.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the JointJS clean version (without jQuery, Lodash, Backbone, Geometry and Vectorizer). You can get this version (together with Geometry and Vectorizer) here: http://jointjs.com/download. Then download Lodash (https://lodash.com/) and Backbone (http://backbonejs.org/) and load everything in the following order:

- jquery
- jquery ui
- jquery layout
- lodash
- backbone
- geometry
- vectorizer
- jointjs clean